# sent multiple attachements with "cmd = echo ..."

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, echo

I using following code to sent mails from linux - I usually only attach one file, but wanted to change that in the coding to enter five files - any idea how?

```
body_text = "This is your Email Body"
title = "This is your Email title"
file = ('location/filename.txt')
cmd = 'echo "'+body_text+'" | mutt -s "'+title+'" -a '+file+' -- email@address.com'
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

I have read so many websites, but none of them used the code I have. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: If this is question is about linux why is the CMD tag used?

Comment: true, thanks for flagging, changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutt takes multiple `-a` when multiple files need to be attached:

https://superuser.com/questions/257963/using-mutt-to-send-2-files

```
body_text = "This is your Email Body"
title = "This is your Email title"
files = ('location/filename.txt', 'other file.txt')
cmd = 'echo "'+body_text+'" | mutt -s "'+title+ '" -a '.join(files) +' -- email@address.com'
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this looks like the solution I was looking for. Unfortunatelly it does not exactly what expected - the cmd variable output here is: 'echo "This is your Email Body" | mutt -s "This is your Email titlelocation/filename.txt" -a other file.txt -- email@address.com'  --- so it looks like it joins the first file name with the title :-/

Comment: I will use a variation of your code, this works! :) thank you!

Comment: file = '/location/file.text';
file2 = '/location/file2.text';
cmd = 'echo "'+body_text+'" | mutt -s "'+title+'" -a '+file+' -a '+file2+' -- email@address.com'

Comment: @Vanassins Well you need to include a space if you want it. `title+ '"` -> `title+ ' "`